# ActiveX Component can't create object(embedded firefox browser)

Tags: vb6

we have deployed VB6.o application on 2003 r2 server into testing server and it's working fine. But, when deployed into production server we are having runtime error "ActiveX component can't create object".
we have recently made changes to call embedded firefox browser.
Could anyone please suggest what could be the reason.

Regards
SSR

Comment: We'd need to see the code and know the line on which it is failing.  . Read up on how best to create a minimal example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .  You can use ProcMon to see what objects your program is trying to create by spying on its registry access.

Answer (score 0):

Check the reference to the firefox browser object on your testing server.

Make sure it's in same location on your production server and it's been registered correctly - I assume you try to install and register it with your VB6 app installer?